# Cómo enviar los enlaces de descarga al navegador chrome desde c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, chrome

Tengo varios links de archivos el cual deseo enviarlo al navegador de descarga de google chrome con un nombre propio.

Ejemplo, tengo la ruta de los siguientes archivo:

```
http://demo001.com/nombre_ejmplo01.html
http://demo001.com/nombre_ejmplo02.html
```

Lo que deseo hacer, es mandar al navegador de descarga de esta manera.

```
http://demo001.com/nombre_ejmplo01.html con el nombre ejemplo0001
http://demo001.com/nombre_ejmplo02.html con el nombre ejemplo0002
```

y así sucesivamente los N archivos.

La idea que tengo en mente es lo siguiente:
Desde visual c# winforms, con solo dar clic al botón, se envié todos los links al navegador de descarga.

El resto de recorrer todos los campos, ya sé cómo realizarlo, lo único que no tengo idea de como hacer, es mandar los archivos al navegador de descarga de google.

En caso que me digan que lo descargue desde un WEBCLIENTE, no me sirve, necesariamente se tiene que enviar los archivos a descargar desde el navegador de google(recomenado), firefox o internet explorer.

Caso contrario, de que otra manera se podría hacer lo que estoy necesitando, capaz crear un archivo batch para que agregue los archivos en el navegador de descargas, pero ¿cómo sería?

Muchas gracias a todos, espero encontrar alguna solución, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En lineas generales la estrategia mas sencilla es que el navegador se conecte al servidor cada x segundos usando Ajax y pregunte ¿hay algo para mi? El servidor dirá que no y así sucesivamente hasta que haya recibido los archivos desde la aplicación Windows. Entonces retornará el Html con los enlaces.

Usando jQuery y MVC Razor puedes hacer esto desde una vista Index.cshtml:

```
var buscarEnlaces = function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("Descargar", "Archivos")', //esto genera la Url
        success: function (respuesta) {
            if (respuesta) {
                $('#enlaces').html(respuesta);
            } else { //la función se llama a si misma luego de 3 segundos
                setTimeout(buscarEnlaces, 3000);
            }
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    buscarEnlaces();
});
```

Del lado del servidor tendrías:

```
public class ArchivosController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Descargar()
    {
        List<Enlace> enlaces = GenerarEnlaces();
        if (enlaces.Count() > 0)
            return View(enlaces);
        else
            return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

y en la partial view "Views/Archivos/Descargar.cshtml" debes declarar el modelo para que lo reciba como parámetro. No incluyas ningún layout ya que solo queremos los enlaces.

```
@model List<MiAplicacion.Models.Enlace>

@foreach(var enlace in Model)
{
    <a href="@enlace.Url">@enlace.Titulo</a>
}
```

Esto es un poco básico para que se entienda. Para que funcione, la vista Index.cshmtl debe tener un div con id "enlaces" y el layout o la vista Index (no ambos) deberían cargar la librería jQuery.

Pero a la larga si es para un proyecto grande yo me crearía una api que retorne Json y dejaría la conexión abierta con Comet.

De todos modos a corto plazo deberías agregar una función para manejar errores y pasarla al Ajax. Así puedes seguir intentando recuperar los enlaces o mostrar un error en caso de que la página no pueda acceder al servidor.